# Update Ubuntu with Gajdaw/ubuntu module

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

i have a Puppet master running on CentOs 7 and i have applied [this](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/gajdaw/ubuntu) module to automaticly update my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Servers.

I have applied these manifests to the master :

```
puppet apply /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/ubuntu/manifests/clean.pp 
puppet apply /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/ubuntu/manifests/update.pp 
puppet apply /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/ubuntu/manifests/upgrade.pp 
puppet apply /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/ubuntu/manifests/init.pp
```

But i am getting this error when i am running 
    puppet agent --test

> Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Platform not supported in module 'ubuntu'. at /etc/puppet/environments/production/modules/ubuntu/manifests/init.pp:15 on node test.home
>   Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
>   Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run

Comment: Have you completed the Puppet Learning VM? You would never apply manifests like that to your master, so there seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding.

Comment: Nope not yet, but i might think it would be a good idea then